# Is there an index that can make the following query faster

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make the following query faster:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) AS rownum
      FROM table
      WHERE user = $1 AND bool_value = False) x
WHERE rownum = $3
```

Is there an index that can do this?

Comment: Faster than what?  What indexes do you already have, and what is the current `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for the query?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest writing this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE user = $1 AND bool_value = False
ORDER BY id
OFFSET $3 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Note that `$3` here is one less than in your version.  And, this doesn't include the row number in the result set -- although you could easily add that if you really do want it.

Then you want an index on `(user, bool_value, id)`.  The first two columns can be in either order.  This index should also work on your query.